# when syncing webservices with SQLite, array and object error appear

Tags: android, json, web-services, sqlite

i am trying to get my json data into my sqlite, from web services to android.

This is the error that i get when i start syncing.

[error stating Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxTOF.png)

The error appear on this chunk of codes.

```
 public String processSync(String response) {
    String status = FAILED;
    try {
        String formattedData = getFormattedData(response);
        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        ProductDataBean[] productDataBeanArray = gson.fromJson(formattedData, ProductDataBean[].class);
        AdministratorHelper administratorHelper = new AdministratorHelper();
        status = administratorHelper.insertProductData(context, productDataBeanArray);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

AdministratorHelper.java

```
public class AdministratorHelper {

DBLiteUtils dbLiteUtils;
AdministratorDao dao = new AdministratorDao();

public String insertProductData(Context context, ProductDataBean[] productDataBeanArray){
    String status = FAILED;
    try{
        dbLiteUtils = new DBLiteUtils(context);
        dbLiteUtils.open();
        status = dao.insertProductData(dbLiteUtils, productDataBeanArray);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        dbLiteUtils.close();
    }
    return status;
}
```

AdministratorDao.java

```
public class AdministratorDao {

private Cursor cursor;

//Insert Product Details into SQLite
public String insertProductData(DBLiteUtils dbLiteUtils, ProductDataBean[] productDataBeanArray){
    String status = FAILED;
    try {
        if(productDataBeanArray.length > 0) {
            //Delete Existing Data
            dbLiteUtils.deleteAll("ProductMaster");

            //Base Insert Query for inserting New Data into ProductMaster Table
            String query = "INSERT INTO ProductMaster(ItemId, Description, Barcode, TransStatusCode) VALUES ";
            //Iterate the productDataBeanArray in order to get productDataBean which contains a single product details
            for (ProductDataBean productDataBean : productDataBeanArray) {
                //Concatenate the Base Insert Query and the product details
                query = query+"('"+productDataBean.getItemId().trim()+"', '"+productDataBean.getDescription().trim().replace("\'", "\'\'")+"', '"+productDataBean.getBarcode().trim()+"', '"+productDataBean.getTransStatusCode().trim()+"'),"; //.trim() removes unwanted empty spaces
            }
            //Remove the last comma from the iterated complete query
            query = query.substring(0, query.length()-1);
            //execute the query
            dbLiteUtils.executeQuery(query);
            //return  success
            status = SUCCESS;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

This is my code in the visual studio to get the json data

```
 public class ProductController : ApiController
{

    public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        List<Product> pproducts;
        using (estocktakeEntities entities = new estocktakeEntities())
        {

            pproducts = entities.Products.ToList();
            //return entities.products.ToList();

        }
        return pproducts;

    }
```

This is a sample of my json

> [{"invtid":"02007997                      ","ib_itemcode1":"0                 ","transtatuscode":"IN","descr":"Pantene C/C Intensive Care Mask 6 x 150m"},
>   {"invtid":"1","ib_itemcode1":"1","transtatuscode":"IN","descr":"object1"},{"invtid":"13101336                      ","ib_itemcode1":"47400179172       ","transtatuscode":"IN","descr":"Gillette Mach 3 Dispenser 8S (X12)                          "},
>   {"invtid":"13101473                      ","ib_itemcode1":"47400179349       ","transtatuscode":"IN","descr":"Gillette Mach3 Cart 4S (X12)

Let me know if more information is needed, i will be more than willing to upload them.

thank you sir for your time.

**EDIT 1**

After trying to debug, i had this error, still not sure is it useful but here is the error and the codes related to it.

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentNullException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)\r\n   at ProductServiceFinal.Controllers.ProductController.Post(Product productrecord)"}

**ProductController.Post**

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Product productrecord)
    {
        try
        {
            using (estocktakeEntities entities = new estocktakeEntities())
            {
                entities.Products.Add(productrecord);
                //entities.Entry(productrecord).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

                entities.SaveChanges();

                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, productrecord);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + productrecord.invtid.ToString());
                return message;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you update this question with full JSON?

Comment: It seems like a Gson error. Could you check this line  `        ProductDataBean[] productDataBeanArray = gson.fromJson(formattedData, ProductDataBean[].class);
` ; try `ProductDataBean.class` than `ProductDataBean[].class`

Comment: @PedroRodrigues hi sir my full jason has 4000 over records. its the same and it will end with a }] .

Comment: @RustFisher hi sir, i try changing it to productDataBean however my "            status = administratorHelper.insertProductData(context, productDataBeanArray);" will result to an error. i will update and show you all the link

Comment: @phan About SQLite, I guess `ContentResolver` may help :)

Comment: @RustFisher sorry sir, could you elaborate more regarding contentresolver. like what am i suppose to do or go about it.

Comment: @phan  Sorry about that :(   I misunderstand .  It is my fault.

Comment: @RustFisher no worry haha, but still how is that able to fix the issue i am having, sorry i am new to this.

Comment: I test your code `processSync(String response)` on my device and works well... If it was me, I would log out every JSON body to see which JSON cause this error.

Comment: @RustFisher alright thats a good news at least, now how do i go about log out every json body...is there a small example

Comment: Em...  Let's add `Log.e("tag", formattedData);` in catch clause of `processSync(String response)`.

Comment: @RustFisher hi sir, i had followed ur suggestion of adding the log and this is what it display, i had updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

The error log is :`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column`  So I guess the problem is JSON body which was web service provided.

```
 public String processSync(String response) {
    String status = FAILED;
    try {
        String formattedData = getFormattedData(response);
        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        ProductDataBean[] productDataBeanArray = gson.fromJson(formattedData, ProductDataBean[].class);
        AdministratorHelper administratorHelper = new AdministratorHelper();
        status = administratorHelper.insertProductData(context, productDataBeanArray);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag",formattedData); // log out this JSON
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

And `EDIT 1` told me that the problem may occur in web service. (I guess web service returns a wrong JSON).
My advice is that add some "fault-tolerance" code to Android project.
The root cause is probably in the web service.

Comment: thank you sir for the suggestion, i will go look up on fault tolerance and mean while update this post with my web services